# problema com uppercase no django

Tags: python, django

Estou com problema de uppercase no django, no codigo a seguir, funciona no primeiro form (nome) e no ultimo form (orgao), porem nos forms intermediarios nao transforma em maiusculas as letras enviadas no banco...

**models.py**

```
class Requerente(models.Model):
NACIONALIDADE = (
    ('BRASILEIRO', 'BRASILEIRO'),
    ('BRASILEIRA', 'BRASILEIRA'),
    ('ESTRANGEIRO', 'ESTRANGEIRO'),
    ('ESTRANGEIRA', 'ESTRANGEIRA'),
    )
ESTADO_CIVIL = (
    ('CASADO', 'CASADO'),
    ('CASADA', 'CASADA'),
    ('SOLTEIRO', 'SOLTEIRO'),
    ('SOLTEIRA', 'SOLTEIRA'),
    ('DIVORCIADO', 'DIVORCIADO'),
    ('DIVORCIADA', 'DIVORCIADA'),
    ('VIÚVO', 'VIÚVO'),
    ('VIÚVA', 'VIÚVA'),
)
REGIME = (
    ('COMUNHAO DE BENS', 'COMUNHAO DE BENS'),
    ('COMUNHAO PARCIAL DE BENS', 'COMUNHAO PARCIAL DE BENS'),
    ('SEPARAÇÃO DE BENS', 'SEPARACAO DE BENS'),
    )
nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
nacionalidade = models.CharField(choices=NACIONALIDADE, max_length=50, null=True)
estado_civil = models.CharField(u'estado civil', max_length=50, choices=ESTADO_CIVIL, null=True)
nubente = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
regime = models.CharField(u'regime', max_length=50, choices=REGIME, blank=True, null=True)
profissao = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
rg = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
orgao = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, )
logradouro = models.ForeignKey(Logradouro, verbose_name=u'Rua, Av.')
numero = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
bairro = models.ForeignKey(Bairro, )
cidade = models.ForeignKey(Cidade)
telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
celular =  models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nome
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.nome = self.nome.upper()
    super(Requerente, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.nubente = self.nubente.upper()
    super(Requerente, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.profissao = self.profissao.upper()
    super(Requerente, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.orgao = self.orgao.upper()
    super(Requerente, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que você não tenta usar somente um `save` e ir tratando esses fields nesse save?

Aqui está uma possível solução, usando um único save para tratar os fields:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.nubente = self.nubente.upper()
    self.profissao = self.profissao.upper()
    self.orgao = self.orgao.upper()

    super(Requerente,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Coloque esse único save no seu Model e tente executar novamente.

Comment: deu certissimo, muito obrigado !!!

Comment: @LucasJunior Show!! Que bom que deu certo. Marque a resposta como a correta para caso alguém mais tenha a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Caso queria, você também pode usar a função clean no models.py para não ter que sobrescrever a função save.

```
    class Requerente(models.Model):

        nacionalidade = models.CharField(choices=NACIONALIDADE, max_length=50, null=True)

        def clean(self):
            self.nacionalidade = str(self.nacionalidade.upper())
```

Assim a gravação e recuperação do banco sempre será em maiúsculo.